# Descargar archivos/imágenes de una pagina con Python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-colab

Me gustaría descargar una serie de imágenes de una [pagina en particular](https://es.99designs.com/inspiration/logos/distressed), y quiero extraer todas las imágenes de logotipos que se muestran. Con lo que llevo hecho he logrado obtener los enlaces de cada imagen como archivo adjunto. Estoy creando algo en `Google Colab` con *Python 3* (primera vez que uso `Google Colab`) y segunda vez con *python*, y esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

url = 'https://es.99designs.com/inspiration/logos/distressed'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')

imagelink = soup.find_all("img")
    
for i in imagelink:
  print(i['data-src'])
```

Con resultado al ejecutar:

```
https://images-platform.99static.com//NM1mPyIyRE5wLx1IdPkKdQGnrb8=/0x0:2000x2000/fit-in/590x590/99designs-contests-attachments/127/127450/attachment_127450343
https://images-platform.99static.com//T71FZNT2lELj2anTyGPux1f78t8=/180x33:834x687/fit-in/500x500/99designs-contests-attachments/40/40590/attachment_40590386
https://images-platform.99static.com//i_BHKETWq8SP9w0X5eZpGifFCYU=/173x38:1135x1000/fit-in/500x500/99designs-contests-attachments/67/67910/attachment_67910319
...
```

Y eso es todo, no tengo idea de cómo descargar esas imágenes y guardarlas en local, ya que en los ejemplos que he visto no figura desde `google colab`. Pude extraer esos enlaces, pero nada más.

Si por favor alguien me puede orientar con algún ejemplo sencillo o algo lo suficientemente claro para poder entender como descargar las imágenes de esos enlaces y guardarlas en mi pc le estaría muy agradecido.

Un abrazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del `for` has una petición al url de cada imagen y guarda el contenido en un archivo (en este caso veo que las imágenes estan en formato `.png`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

url = 'https://es.99designs.com/inspiration/logos/distressed'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')

imgHtmlList = soup.find_all("img")
    
for i in imgHtmlList:
    imgUrl= i['data-src'] #Esto es lo que extrae el url de las etiquetas <img>
    img = requests.get(imgUrl) #petición al url de la imagen
    name = imgUrl.split("/")[-1] #este nombre esta simplemente para no nombrar yo mismo el archivo
    open(name+'.png','wb').write(img.content) #abrir/crear un archivo .png con el contenido de la imagen a descargar
    print('descargando: {}.png'.format(name))
```

Prueba:

```
descargando: attachment_127450343.png
descargando: attachment_40590386.png
descargando: attachment_67910319.png
...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sencillamente perfecto, eso era lo que estaba intentando hacer, con tu solución me quedó mucho mas claro, muchas gracias de verdad. Ahora una última consulta ¿Dónde quedan almacenadas esas imágenes? Lo estoy corriendo el Google Colab y si bien trabaja de manera correcta, desconozco completamente donde quedan descargadas las imágenes. También quise correrlo en mi computadora, pero estoy usando Windows 7 y la versión actual de Python 3 no corre en W7, y con mi version actual de Python instalada ya no puedo descargar BS4 por falta de soporte en W7.

Comment: Quedan almacenados en la misma dirección donde se encuentre el archivo python en ejecución. También uso W7. Descarga la última versión de python disponible para W7 (3.8.9) con esta podrás descargar la última versión de BS4 para esta versión :)

Comment: Listo, ya estoy descargando el Python 3.8.9 muchas gracias por el dato y por la respuesta anterior